# gnome--terminal -e option not executing?

Tags: shell, gnome-terminal

I want to open my terminal with some commands executed in it on bootup. So I wrote a script with following line in it:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "MyPC" -e "sh -c 'firefox &;exec bash'" --tab -t "MYPC2" -e "sh -c 'ls;exec bash'"
```

In this `firefox &` is not executing, however if I write only `firefox` it executes.
So only the second tab is opening not the first one

I know it's some spacing issue. If I write just `ls` that also executes.

What is the correct syntax? Why is it not taking spacing??

Comment: How do you invoke this at boot up of the computer? How do wait for X to start?

Comment: +1 to make up for the uncommented downvote. Don't see anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `;` after a `&` does not work. `&` is already a command separator, specifying, that the command should be run in the background, so `;` is not required.

Try removing the `;` and report back.

Comment: It worked after removing `;`. Thanks

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha Glad I could help and welcome to Unix&Linux SE.